# Showing that a recursive sequence is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I have a sequence: $x_{n+2} = \sqrt{x_{n+1}x_n}$, with $0<a\leq x_1 \leq x_2 \leq b$

I know that $ |x_{n+1}-x_n|=\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}|x_n-x_{n-1}| $  or $|x_{n+1}-x_n|=(\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}})^{n-1}|x_2-x_1|$, and that the limit of this expression $\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, but I can't really figure out how to approach the $n>m$ part of this proof. If someone could give some pointers it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $|x_n-x_{n-1}| \leq Ac^{n}$ with $0<c<1$ im plies that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy. Just use triangle inequality and the fact that $\sum_{k=n}^{m} c^{k} \to 0$ as $n  \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have $|x_{n+1}-x_n|\leq c q^n$ with $c>0$ and $0<q<1$, you can telescope. This means
$$
|x_{n+k}-x_n|=|\sum_{j=1}^kx_{n+j}-x_{n+j-1}|\leq \sum_{j=1}^k|x_{n+j}-x_{n+j-1}|=\sum_{j=1}^kcq^{n+j-1}=\frac{cq^n(1-q^k)}{1-q}\leq\frac{cq^n}{1-q}.
$$
Now given $\varepsilon>0$, if you choose $n$ such that $\frac{cq^n}{1-q}<\varepsilon$, you get $|x_m-x_n|<\varepsilon$ for all $m\geq n$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :
Firstly, go for m>n and use $|x_m - x_n| \le |x_m - x_{m-1}|+|x_{m-1} - x_{m-2}|+....+|x_{n+1} - x_n|$.
Now plug in all the values.